# Detecting if WebView2 Runtime is installed with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript, webview2

There is a good discussion about this here on the Microsoft website:

[Detect if a suitable WebView2 Runtime is already installed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#detect-if-a-suitable-webview2-runtime-is-already-installed)

In part, it states:

> Inspect the `pv` (`REG_SZ`) regkey for the WebView2 Runtime at both of the
> following registry locations. The `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` regkey is used
> for per-machine install. The `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` regkey is used for
> per-user install.
>
> For WebView2 applications, at least one of these regkeys must be
> present and defined with a version greater than `0.0.0.0`. If neither
> regkey exists, or if only one of these regkeys exists but its value is
> `null`, an *empty string*, or `0.0.0.0`, this means that the WebView2
> Runtime isn't installed on the client. Inspect these regkeys to detect
> whether the WebView2 Runtime is installed, and to get the version of
> the WebView2 Runtime. Find `pv` (`REG_SZ`) at the following two locations.
>
> The two registry locations to inspect on 64-bit Windows:
>
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}`
> - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}`
>
> The two registry locations to inspect on 32-bit Windows:
>
> - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}`
> - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}`

---

My installer uses elevation so I have limited my checks to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. I believe this was the correct thing to do. This is my attempt at writing this function:

```pascal
function IsWebView2RuntimeNeeded(): boolean;
var
    Version: string;
    RuntimeNeeded: boolean;
    VerifyRuntime: boolean;
begin
    { See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#detect-if-a-suitable-webview2-runtime-is-already-installed }

    RuntimeNeeded := true;
    VerifyRuntime := false;

    { Since we are using an elevated installer I am not checking HKCU }
    if (IsWin64) then
    begin
        { Test x64 }
        if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}', 'pv', Version)) then
        begin
            { We need to verify }
            VerifyRuntime := true;
        end
    else
    begin
        { Test x32 }
        if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}', 'pv', Version)) then
        begin
            { We need to verify }
            VerifyRuntime := true;
        end;
    end;

    { Verify the version information }
    if (VerifyRuntime) then
    begin
        if (not Version = '' and not Version = '0.0.0.0') then
            Log('WebView2 Runtime is installed');
            RuntimeNeeded := false;
        else
            Log('WebView2 Runtime needs to be downloaded and installed');
        end;
    end;

    Result := RuntimeNeeded;
end;
```

But it will not compile and says:

> Column 40 type mismatch.

It doesn't like this line:

`if (not Version = '' and not Version = '0.0.0.0') then`

I am not confident writing native Pascal Script so I appreciate guidance on correcting or improving this code so that it works efficiently.

---

I am comfortable with the other aspects of actually downloading the file and starting its installer because I can follow the principle for the other downloads in my setup script. It is just putting this actual test together to verify if the WebView2 runtime is installed or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to glean some advice from one of the comments to this question on another website:

[How to write an `if and` statement?](https://forum.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=18712.0)

---

My current code is now:

```pascal
function IsWebView2RuntimeNeeded(): boolean;
var
    Version: string;
    RuntimeNeeded: boolean;
    VerifyRuntime: boolean;
begin
    { See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/distribution#detect-if-a-suitable-webview2-runtime-is-already-installed }

    RuntimeNeeded := true;
    VerifyRuntime := false;

    { Since we are using an elevated installer I am not checking HKCU }
    if (IsWin64) then
    begin
        { Test x64 }
        if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}', 'pv', Version)) then
        begin
            { We need to verify }
            VerifyRuntime := true;
        end
    else
    begin
        { Test x32 }
        if (RegQueryStringValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\EdgeUpdate\Clients\{F3017226-FE2A-4295-8BDF-00C3A9A7E4C5}', 'pv', Version)) then
        begin
            { We need to verify }
            VerifyRuntime := true;
        end;
    end;

    { Verify the version information }
    if (VerifyRuntime) then
    begin
        if (Version <> '') and (Version <> '0.0.0.0') then
        begin
            Log('WebView2 Runtime is installed');
            RuntimeNeeded := false;
        end
        else
            Log('WebView2 Runtime needs to be downloaded and installed');
        end;
    end;

    Result := RuntimeNeeded;
end;
```

I also had to add the `begin` and `end` keywords to that `if` statement. Feel free to update or add your own answer if you can see a more efficient way to write this code. For example, the original article I linked to mentioned an alternative ([`GetAvailableCoreWebView2BrowserVersionString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl?view=webview2-1.0.1210.39#:%7E:text=unable%20to%20start.-,GetAvailableCoreWebView2BrowserVersionString,-public%20STDAPI%20GetAvailableCoreWebView2BrowserVersionString)). I assume we can't use that approach.

Comment: When I installed the WebView2 on Windows 8 using the online installer, it automatically installed the component only for the current user. Your code then reported the WebView2 is not installed because it does not search in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` registry key. To improve your answer, I would also consider adding this second check. Anyway, thank you for a useful piece of code!

Comment: @HonzaVojtěch Feel free to edit my answer and add an addendum. And if you have any official link … to documentation.